# Pass Email Over URL with UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just working on an unsafe feature for logging in a user. How do you pass an email address over the URL? I keep getting the `cannot get /` error.

Url looks like this:

`/login?company=1234&user=test%40testuser.com`

```
$stateProvider
        .state('auth.login', {
            url: '/login?company&username&password',
            title: 'Login',
            controller: 'Login',
            templateUrl: 'x/login',
            authentication: false,
            params: {
                company: null,
                username: null,
                user: null
            }
        });
```

Logic for logging in

```
if ($stateParams.password) {
            $scope.credentials = {
                company: $stateParams.company,
                username: $stateParams.username || $stateParams.user,
                password: $stateParams.password,
            };

            login($scope.credentials);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#params you shouldn't use url and params together (I would remove the params).

Additionally you are using the param *user* in the url instead of *username* like you have defined it. I think you want to support both so you should add the user as a query param too.

The encoding of the email should be fine.

The routing error itself may be caused by a missing config of html5mode (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode). Did you try it with a leading #?